Type predicate "adds" to type instead of replacing
I have a class with a generic type representing the known elements of its map, like so:
abstract class Component { ... }

class Test<Known extends Component[]> {
    components: Map<string, Component> ...

    has<C extends Component>(comp: C): this is Test<[...Known, C]> {
       ...
    }
}

My hope is that I could use Test.has() to change its type when checking for available components, however, it appends to the type instead of replacing:
// test is Test<[AComp, BComp]>, so far so good
const test = new Test<[AComp, BComp]>();

const comp = new CComp();

if (sometest.has(comp)) {
    // now test is "Test<[AComp, BComp]> & Test<[AComp, BComp, CComp]>"
}

Basically, test.has() gets the right type but instead of replacing it, it "ands" it.
I do believe this is working as intended for the TypeScript engine as it doesn't understand the second type actually extends the first and believes they should be treated as distinct things.
How would I would tell the engine that the second extends the first, is it even possible?
Edit with Reproducible example:
abstract class Component {
}
class AComp extends Component {
  aValue = 1;
}
class BComp extends Component {
  bValue = 3;
}
type ClassOf<C extends Component> = new (...args: any[]) => C;
type TestGetResult<C extends Component, K extends Component[]> = C extends K[number] ? C : (C | undefined); 
class Test<K extends Component[]> {
  components = new Map<string, Component>();
  constructor(components: Component[]) {
    components.forEach(comp => this.components.set(comp.constructor.name, comp));
  }

  has<C extends Component>(comp: ClassOf<C>): this is Test<[...K, C]> {
    return [...this.components.keys()].includes(comp.name);
  }

  get<C extends Component>(comp: ClassOf<C>): TestGetResult<C, K> {
    return this.components.get(comp.name) as TestGetResult<C, K>; 
  }
}
// This class simulates us getting the Test instances from somewhere else in the code, their type is not immediately known when we return them but by
// using .has() we can infer some of it
class SomeStore {
  list: Test<any>[] = [];
  add(test: Test<any>) { this.list.push(test); }

  getTestWithSomeComponent<C extends Component>(comp: ClassOf<C>): Test<[C]> {
    for (let test of this.list) {
      if (test.has(comp)) {
        return test;
      }
    }
    throw new Error('No test found');
  }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const store = new SomeStore();
const test1 = new Test<[AComp, BComp]>([new AComp(), new BComp()])
store.add(test1);                                                
                                                                
const testAfterGet = store.getTestWithSomeComponent(AComp);
if (testAfterGet.has(BComp)) {
  const a = testAfterGet.get(AComp);
  // Here is the issue
  const b = testAfterGet.get(BComp) // at this point, testAfterGet has the 'and' type
  console.log(a.aValue); 
  console.log(b.bValue); // b should not be undefined
}



Please [edit] to provide a [mre] without pseudocode or missing declarations. The answer to this question might be "use Extract", but you don't have any dependency on Known whatsoever in the code shown (except for the result of the type predicate). You are claiming that the second type extends the first, but if that turns out to be false then nothing we suggest will work. A [mre] where your claim is verifiable would be very helpful.  The goal here is that we take your code, paste it into our IDE, see your issue jump out at us as the only problem, fix the type predicate, and see it work.

(see prev comment) and what is Entity?

My bad, Entity was a typo and is supposed to be Test, I will add a reproducible example soon

@jcalz I've edited my post with an example, I'm also looking into Extract but it's still a bit confusing

As written, Test<[AComp, BComp]> extends Test<[AComp]> is false. (you can verify this by checking type X = Test<[AComp, BComp]> extends Test<[AComp]> ? true : false.) You may only narrow using type predicates, and you're not doing that, so this can never work as asked. Please [edit] your example to make sure that you're really narrowing, or else the answer to this question will be "you're doing it wrong". Let me know how you'd like to proceed.

@jcalz thanks, as I thought, the types don't "really" extend eachother, it's more of an abstraction. I don't really have any idea of how a similar logic would be attainable so I will mark this as answered, but if you have any suggestion I would be glad to hear it

That would depend on the details of what you're trying to do in a way I'm not prepared to delve into. If it were an actual subtype you could use Extract. I think I'll just write an answer documenting how type guard functions work and if you can't figure it out then you can open a new question for it, with enough of a [mre] that's as simple as possible and explains what you're trying to do clearly.

A custom type guard method that returns this is X can only work properly if the type of X is assignable to the type of object being checked.  That is, type guard functions and methods only narrow types, they don't arbitrarily mutate types.  The intersection this & X is, by definition, a narrowing of this, so that type will always work.
If you don't like that, then you could try things like Extract<X, this> with the Extract utility type, but if X really isn't assignable to this, then Extract<X, this> will probably be never and that won't do what you want.
Since, in your example, Test<[AComp, BComp]> is not assignable to Test<[AComp]>:
declare const x: Test<[AComp, BComp]>;
const y: Test<[AComp]> = x; // error!
// Type 'Test<[AComp, BComp]>' is not assignable to type 'Test<[AComp]>'.

That can't work as requested directly.

Intersections should generally do what you want... but for methods they do result in what looks like an overload. If you don't mind overloads but want to change their order, you can explicitly annotate the return type as the intersection in the other order (e.g., X & this instead of this & X):
has<C extends Component>(comp: ClassOf<C>): this is Test<[...K, C]> & this {
    return [...this.components.keys()].includes(comp.name);
}

And now things work with your particular example code:
const testAfterGet = store.getTestWithSomeComponent(AComp);
if (testAfterGet.has(BComp)) {
    // const testAfterGet: Test<[AComp, BComp]> & Test<[AComp]>
    const a = testAfterGet.get(AComp);
    //    ^? const a: AComp
    const b = testAfterGet.get(BComp);
    //    ^? const b: BComp
    console.log(a.aValue);
    console.log(b.bValue); // b should not be undefined
}

But it's not 100% clear that this will behave as desired for your entire code base.

Ideally you would refactor so that Test<X> extends Test<Y> if and only if X and Y hold some obvious simple relationship to each other. For the code as written it's hard to tell. You seem to be using tuple types which care about the order of these types, but I don't think you actually do care about that? Or at least the example code doesn't motivate it (how could you tell the difference between a Test<[AComp, BComp]> and a Test<[BComp, AComp]> given the structure of your code, especially since the constructor of Test<K> doesn't seem to care about K at all?  I'll consider such refactoring out of scope for this question as asked.
Playground link to code
